How can I create a sphere of luminous dots with a wavy effect in Inkscape?
I'm trying to replicate a visual effect similar to the one shown in the image below using Inkscape. The image features a sphere composed of numerous small dots with a glowing, luminous appearance and a 3D wavy effect.
Design I want : 
Could someone guide me through the steps or techniques required to achieve this design in Inkscape?
Thank you for your help!

7 questions at once? Are you anticipating some sort of "tutorial on demand"? The reality is, this was most probably created in a 3D app where textures and lighting are easier.

This looks like a 3D render, not a vector graphic. Inkscape is not suitable - its' 2D software and has no true 3D features. It's not the right kind of software for the job. You'd be better with 3D modeling software, like Blender (which is free).  There's a Blender Stack Exchange if you get stuck.

@Scott not 7 but 1 . How to create this kinda pattern?

Did you miss your own 7 bullet points,  all asking a different question?

The luminous appearance of the dots is caused by the dark background. The dots themselves cannot be any brighter nor more colorful than what's available on the display.
My best guess (the same as already said in comments): The dots are a regular pattern laid on a complex 3D surface in a 3D program. The brightness and color variations could be made by placing the right lights around the 3D scene. The color variations could also be in the pattern or they can be inserted afterwards to the rendered image.
In theory one could warp a regular dot pattern to the same apparent form in a 2D program and paint the color and light variations manually. But the effort and the needed amount of skill would be extreme. Inkscape is a poor tool if you try the warping approach. Photoshop or Affinity Photo are better, but they work with bitmap images. Illustrator has an efficient warping tool (envelope distort) which can modify as well vector as bitmap images, but I wouldn't try with it anything this complex.
Inkscape doesn't have anything comparable.There one should insert the dots manually. It is theoretically possible if one can imagine the wanted result beforehand. You have seen it, so drawing a copy needs only inserting the same dots one by one. I guess you are not going to do it.
The used 3D surface is complex. But it's nothing special for those who can make 3D models of organic shapes (people, animals, plants).
To show some evidence of the power of the 3D approach I dug up my (idiotic*) attempt to make a 3D model of a flower petal in the same way as one can make surfaces for engineering drawings  i.e. by blending between a few profile curves:

The petal is in the left. In the right the background is changed to black and the texture photo placed on the surface is replaced by a regular pattern of cyan dots.
The dot size variations are caused by the density variations in the internal surface (UV) coordinates, which (harmfully) is out of the user control at least in simplest 3D programs.
The light variations are a part of the default shading in the 3D program. The viewing direction is changed to find the position where the default light makes some glosses, but not so much that the cyan color turns to white.
*) A flat texture photo doesn't make it look alive. Realistic look needs fine 3D details. Surface materials in pro quality 3D modelling programs allows them as bump and normal maps.
